# Unity3D C# calculate correct forward after rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting my development using Unity.
I'm doing something like that:

```
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))newValues[1]-=this.turnSpeed*(float)Time.deltaTime;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))newValues[1]+=this.turnSpeed*(float)Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Rotate(0, newValues[1], 0);


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))newValues[0]+=this.speed*transform.forward.z*(float)Time.deltaTime;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))newValues[0]-=this.speed*transform.forward.z*(float)Time.deltaTime;


    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, (float)newValues[0]);
```

So i rotate and i can move, but it moves just in the Z line, i know i'm calling the Z specific movement.
But with Javascript i can do something

```
     transform.forward+=this.speed*transform.forward*(float)Time.deltaTime;
```

So i don't need to do the new vector process and copy to a separate variable and it works like a charm, using the rotation and using as orientation to himself when it's rotated.

Comment: You should probably edit your title and tag. The unity tag as used refers to the dependency injection container in the MS application block. You're probably referring to unity-3D, also if this is for gaming you might want to add an appropriate tag.

Comment: What happens if you put `transform.forward+=this.speed*transform.forward*(float)Time.deltaTime;` in the C# code?  The Javascript and C# each compile to the same .NET intermediate language, so almost anything possible in one is possible in the other, if coded a little differently.

Comment: It dont work, it is a read only variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may misunderstand the usage of transform.forward. 
**transform.forward** is just a vector to tell you what direction your gameObject faces, it depends on transform.rotation.

If you want to move your GameObject, always use **transform.position**:

```
 transform.position += this.speed * transform.forward * (float)Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how i implement the rotation?

Comment: very old thread , but would like to revive it as you have mentioned "If you want to move your GameObject, always use transform.position" actually if the game object is rigidbody then it should be moved by adding force as directly modifying transform may lead to unrealistic behaviors . But for kinematic bodies your statement is true